# I have a two Model related to each other and I want to automatically create the data on ModelB upon creating the data in ModelA

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have this `User` Model Which came from the User of Django Admin

```
class NewUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    objects = CustomAccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['user_name', 'first_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id) + " " + self.email
```

And I have another model related to this `User` model called `Promoter` model

```
class Promoter(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        NewUser,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user.id) + " " + self.user.email

    def email(self):
        return self.user.email
```

And every time I added a data into User I want to Automatically add also a data into the `Promoter` model with a link to newly created `User`

This is my code in added/registering a new User

```
class RegisterView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            newuser = serializer.save()
           

            if newuser:
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I try to manually add the newly created `User` into the front end by having a two different API call both for adding User and adding promoter but I'm getting an error in adding a Promoter data manually `(1048, "Column 'user_id' cannot be null")`

I also try to adding data using postman [image]

Comment: Are you aware of `signals`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an error for `user` field saved without adding the user object of foreign key

you can pass the user object in the save() method like this...

```
def post(self, request):
    serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        newuser = serializer.save(user=request.user)
```

Comment: I already solve the issue. The problem is I'm passing the `user` id instead of passing the whole user object . Just like what you have mention . I make the code like this. 
(`user = request.data.get('user') 
userId = NewUser.objects.get(pk=user) 
serializer.save(user=userId)`)